# How to delete a parent folder that holds php and html files

Tags: seo, web-hosting, web-development, website-design, shared-hosting

In my hosting structure I have website1, website2 etc. I made a mistake and placed my files and folders inside a folder called source while uploading them to the website1 folder. So now I'm stuck with this source folder. The landing page is fine and it's www.example.com, but subdirectories show up as www.example.com/source/sub.html. So what's the safest way to get rid of the source folder so they read www.example.com/sub.html? Would I crash the site if I just delete the source folder and upload the folders and files directly under website1?

The reason I'm worried is that my hosting company messed up and did a 301 without my knowledge but would this 301 direct affect anything in this process? Thanks much

Comment: What was the 301 redirect that they did? Are they redirecting everything from /* to /source/* ? As long as there aren't links to /source/* files, you should be able to just re-upload them and have your hosting company remove the 301 redirect (if they're redirecting as I guessed).

Comment: What happens when one accesses www.example.com/sub.html in a utility that shows html headers such as CURL?

Comment: Was the site created in some sort of CMS or manually?  Because you may need to tweak some settings.

Comment: I guess now I'm wondering what happens to users that have bookmarked pages. So if the bookmark is www.example.com/source/sub.html and I change it, I'm thinking the bookmark/browser will see www.example.com and then look for source folder next and not find it and throw a 404, would it?

Comment: Actually I just thought of another possible disaster; we've pasted hundreds of links in social media. So when users click these link we pasted weeks ago will also have "source" in the path. Just not sure how that works and if browser is smart enough to located the sub.html. With my minimal knowledge I'd say no, it can't find it. But thanks for all the hints.